# How to display all the category names and images from categories listed from a custom post taxonomy in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

I have created a custom post type named as Products and a custom taxonomy as Product Categories. I have listed a number of product category names with their images in the taxonomy Product Categories. I wanted to display all product category names with their respective images uploaded(uploaded using category image plugin). Images should be uploaded into an `<a>` tag. I don't know how to display the category names and their images.Ihave used the types plugin to create custom post type and taxonomy and category image plugin to load the category image. I wanted to display the group of category names and their image in the below code :

```
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
  <a href="pvc_hose.html">
    <div class="service wow slideInLeft">
      <div class="icon"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/buiding/icon18.png"></div>
      <h4>PVC hose</h4>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

Can anyone help me on this ?

I have attached the screenshot of the product categories.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If I understand properly this is correct way,
First you need to create menu in word press admin menu blank menu. Now go to function.php file (theme file) add following code in it.

You can get products cateogorty list from this function,

```
function get_product_terms( $term_id ) {

        $html = '';

        $args = array( 'hide_empty' => 0, 'parent' => $term_id );

        $terms = get_terms('product_cat', $args);

        foreach ($terms as $term) {

            $html .= '<li';

            if( $term_id == 0 ) {

                $html .= ' class="top_li"';

            }

            $html .= '><a href="'.get_term_link($term->slug, 'product_cat').'">' . $term->name . '</a>';    

            if( $list = get_product_terms( $term->term_id )) {

                $html .= '<ul class="second_level">'.$list.'</ul>';

            }

            $html .= '</li>';

        }

        return $html;

    }
```

You can add products category to menu using this function,

```
// Filter wp_nav_menu() to add additional links and other output
function new_nav_menu_items($items) {
    // Woo function

    /*//product_cat
    $terms = get_terms( 'product_cat', $args );
    print_r($terms);*/
    if( $list = get_product_terms( 0 )) {



    $menu1link = '<li class="home"><a href="' . home_url( '/' ) . '">' . __($list) . '</a></li>';
    $homelink = '<li class="home"><a href="' . home_url( '/' ) . '">' . __('Home') . '</a></li>';
    // add the home link to the end of the menu
    $items = $items . $homelink;
    $items = $items .$menu1link;
    }
    return $items;

}
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_items', 'new_nav_menu_items' );
```

Comment: Second functio write for the menu from product category.`$list` have all category that you want

Comment: I already created the custom post type "Products" and taxonomy for it as "Product Categories" using the types plugin. Then  I added the group of category names in the taxonomy in that "Product Categories" and category images using categories images plugins.I dnt know how to display their images and category names in wordpress ?

Answer (score 0):

Display category image on single product page

```
$terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'product_cat' );
foreach ( $terms as $term ){
  $category_name = $term->name;
  $category_thumbnail = get_woocommerce_term_meta($term->term_id, 'thumbnail_id', true);
  $image = wp_get_attachment_url($category_thumbnail);
  echo '<img class="absolute category-image" src="'.$image.'">';
}
```

Comment: can you tell me please

Comment: Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\xampp\htdocs\Working-files\rajab\wp-content\themes\rajab\page-templates\building.php

Comment: its php foreach error,you can check function output just print_r();

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
                 $terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'product-category' );

                foreach ( $terms as $term ){
               $category_name = $term->name;
             $category_thumbnail = get_woocommerce_term_meta($term->term_id, 'thumbnail_id', true);
            $image = wp_get_attachment_url($category_thumbnail);
                  ?>
            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
                <a href="">
                <div class="service wow slideInLeft">
                    <div class="icon"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/buiding/icon18.png"></div>
                    <h4><?php echo $category_name; ?></h4>
                </div>
                </a>
            </div>

            <?php }   ?>
```

I have added this code.but not working.Its showing an error like this "Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\xampp\htdocs\Working-files\rajab\wp-content\themes\rajab\page-templates\building.php"

Answer (score 0):

very old post, but if someone stills looking for an answer on that, I have done it this way:

```
<?php
                        
    $orderby = 'name';
    $order = 'asc';
    $hide_empty = false;
    $cat_args = array(
          'orderby' => $orderby,
          'order' => $order,
           'hide_empty' => $hide_empty,
    );
    $product_categories = get_terms('projects-category', $cat_args); //your custom category taxonomy
    //var_dump($product_categories); //do var_dump in order to get the '_category_options', that I have
    if (!empty($product_categories)) {
       foreach ($product_categories as $key => $category) {
            $term_image = get_term_meta($category->term_id, '_category_options', true);
            $url = wp_get_attachment_image_src($term_image['category_image'], array(678, 420) ); //custom display image dimensions, according to your needs
?>
<img src="<?php echo $url[0]; ?> width="<?php echo $url[1]; ?>" height="<?php echo $url[2]; ?>" />
<?php
             } //end foreach loop
       } //end if
?>
```